# Nav in Flash with AS3. Code not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Im having trouble getting my nav code working. I am not very proficient in actionscript, can anyone spot out what im doing wrong? Thanks in advance

```
//nav
var home:int = 1;
var about:int = 2;
var projects:int = 3;
var press_id:int = 4;
var contact:int = 5;

home_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, home);
about_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, about);
projects_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,projects);
press_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, press_id);
contact_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, contact);



function navbuttonclick(event:MouseEvent, myFrame:Number):void {
            gotoAndStop(myFrame);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: where is the eventlistener for navbuttonclick ?

Comment: Why are you trying to use ints where you should have functions? O.o

Answer (score 3):

```
//define frame indices
const HOME_FRAME:uint = 1;
const ABOUT_US_FRAME:uint = 2;

//set listeners
home_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, home_mc_clickHandler);
home_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, about_mc_clickHandler);

//define listeners
function home_mc_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    changePage(HOME_FRAME);
}

function about_mc_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    changePage(ABOUT_US_FRAME);
}

//change location
function changePage(frameIndex:uint):void
{
    gotoAndStop(frameIndex);
}
```